# Establishing an upper bound for a dyadic average of a function in $ {L^{p}}([0,1)) $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, integration

Suppose that $ f $ is $ 1 $-periodic and that $ f \in {L^{p}}([0,1)) $, where $ p > 1 $. Let
$$
(D_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} =
\left( \left\{
I^{n}_{j} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \left[ \frac{j}{2^{n}},\frac{j + 1}{2^{n}} \right)
~ \Bigg| ~
j \in \{ 0,\ldots,2^{n} - 1 \}
\right\} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}}
$$
be the sequence of dyadic partitions of $ [0,1) $.

Next, define a sequence $ (F_{n}: [0,1) \to \mathbb{C})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $ of functions by
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}, ~ \forall x \in [0,1), ~
\forall j \in \{ 0,\ldots,2^{n} - 1 \}: \\
{F_{n}}(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\frac{1}{\left| I^{n}_{j} \right|} \int_{I^{n}_{j}} f(t) ~ \mathrm{d}{t}, \quad
\text{if $ x \in I^{n}_{j} \in D_{n} $}.
$$

> **Question.** Is it true that $ \displaystyle \| f - F_{n} \|_{{L^{p}}([0,1))} \leq \sup_{|t| \leq 2^{- n}} \| f(\bullet + t) - f(\bullet) \|_{{L^{p}}([0,1))} $?

Comment: One may need to make more precise what "best upper bound" means here.  Otherwise, the best upper bound for $\|f-F_n\|_{L^p([0,1])}$ will just be $\|f-F_n\|_{L^p([0,1])}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is  known the sequence $\|f-F_{n}\|_{L^{p}([0,1])}$ tends to $0.$ I need to find the speed of convergence. I think it will be $L^{p}([0,1])$ integral modulus of continuity $\omega_{p}(2^{-n}, f)$  i.e., above sequence. Is it true?

Comment: One can pointwise upper bound $|f(x)-F_n(x)|$ by a constant times the average of $|f(x+t)-f(x)|$ for $|t| \leq 2^{-n}$, and the upper bound you want then follows from the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Terry Tao. Thank you very much. Sorry I haven't understood very well. Could you explain a little bit more.

Comment: If $x \in I_j^n$, then $|f(x) - F_n(x)| \leq 2^n \int_{I_j^n} |f(x) - f(y)|\ dy \leq 2^n \int_{|t| \leq 2^{-n}} |f(x+t)-f(x)|\ dt$, by the triangle inequality followed by a change of variable.  If one then uses Minkowski's integral inequality, one obtains the desired inequality losing a factor of $2$.  It may be possible though to improve the loss of $2$ with a more careful argument.