# An upper bound for a average of a function in $L_{p}([0,1))$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, integration

Suppose that $ f $ is $ 1 $-periodic and that $ f \in {L^{p}}([0,1) $, where $ p > 1 $. Let
$$
(D_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} =
\left( \left\{
I^{n}_{j},~ 
1\leq j \leq 2^{n} \}
\right\} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}}
$$
be a sequence of  partitions of $ [0,1) $ such that 
$$\underset{1\leq j\leq 2^{n}}{\max}|I^{n}_{j}|\leq \lambda ^{n} $$
for some $\lambda \in (0,1).$

Next, define a sequence $ (F_{n}: [0,1) \to \mathbb{C})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $ of functions by
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}, ~ \forall x \in [0,1), ~
\forall j \in \{ 1,\ldots,2^{n}  \}: \\
{F_{n}}(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\frac{1}{\left| I^{n}_{j} \right|} \int_{I^{n}_{j}} f(t) ~ \mathrm{d}{t}, \quad
\text{if $ x \in I^{n}_{j} \in D_{n} $}.
$$

> **Question.** Is it true that $ \displaystyle \| f - F_{n} \|_{{L^{p}}([0,1))} \leq \sup_{|t| \leq \lambda^{ n}} \| f(\bullet + t) - f(\bullet) \|_{{L^{p}}([0,1))} $?
>
> Or what kind of estimates can be obtained for $ \displaystyle \| f - F_{n} \|_{{L^{p}}([0,1))}$ depending on $\lambda^{n}$?

**Note that** if $(D_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}}$ is the sequence of dyadic partitions then the inequality [is true](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184467/establishing-an-upper-bound-for-a-dyadic-average-of-a-function-in-lp0-1), in the proof of this inequality I used the equality of the lengths of atoms of  dyadic partition. But in case of different lengths of atoms  I have got some problem.

Comment: You don't need a sequence of partitions. It's enough to prove the inequality for a single partition with arbitrary diameter in (0,1). The number of atoms also seems irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I agree with your comment. During my study I faced such problem and I have put this problem without any changes. Thank you